# Google Apps Script or formula to perform data validation on times entered into cells

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have a cell on a timesheet that collects the 'IN' time; and then a cell that collects the 'OUT' time so that the number of hours can be calculated. I'd like to add some data validation so that the 'OUT' time cannot be earlier than the 'IN' time.
Cell A1 (IN time): 10:00 AM;  Cell B1 (OUT time): 8:00 AM. I would like to produce an alert or something that says:  OUT time cannot be earlier than the IN time. I haven't been able to figure out how to do this. Can someone help me with this? Thank you.

Comment: How about an onEdit function that tests for a new value in Column B, compares the two time values. If the out is earlier than the in, then use an `UI` alert.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## Solution

You can simply compare the values in each cell with an `if` condition inside an [onEdit](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers#onedite) function. Here is the piece of code self explained with comments that satisfies your requirements:

```js
function onEdit() {
  // get the current sheet
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  
  // get values for the cells where we have our in and out time
  var In = ss.getRange('A1').getValue();
  var Out = ss.getRange('B1').getValue();
  
  // if time in is higher than time out
  if(In>Out){
    // prompt alert in the UI of the spreadsheet
    SpreadsheetApp.getUi().alert('Time In cant be higher than time Out');
  }
}
```

I hope this has helped you. Let me know if you need anything else or if you did not understood something. :)

Comment: Yes! Thank you, this is what I need. I would like to ask how it would be handled when there are many scenarios on one sheet (if this needs to be a new question, I understand).  The timesheet covers two weeks, with three places to enter an IN and OUT in one day - so that makes 42 instances. It sounds like an array to me, but I'm not sure how to handle it in code, looping, etc.. Do you have any suggestions?

Comment: Yes, this should actually be posted in another question but just to give you some inspiration you could get the desired ranges and then using a ```for``` loop over the length of the array checking if every value satisfies the condition. It could be something like this ```for(i=0; i<VALUESIN.length; i++){ if( VALUESIN[i] > VALUESOUT[i] ){ TRIGGER THE ALARM }}```

Comment: Thank you so much Mateo! I will work with this and if I do have difficulty understanding it, I will post it as another question. Again, thanks for the inspiration!!! :)